# ggplot2 transforming one axis with log transformation with the other axis as a factor

Tags: r, ggplot2, coordinate-transformation

I am working on a forest plot to visualize prevalence ratios of health behavior in two different time periods. I have the plot working fine, but I need to log transform the continuous numeric axis because this is a prevalence ratio. I tried doing it two different ways, but neither seems to be working. Note: I'm transforming the Y-axis in my plot below, because I used coord_flip to put the labels on the left and the continuous axis on the bottom.

This is what my plot looks like now, and an example of the data & code is below.

[image]

```
label <- c("X1","X2")
PR <- c(1.08, 0.97)
lowlim <- c(0.99, 0.95)
uplim <- c(1.17, 0.98)
rowlab <- c("Sex in the Last 12 Months",
            "Condom Use")

forestdat <- data.frame(label, PR, lowlim, uplim)
forestdat$label <- factor(forestdat$label, levels=rev(forestdat$label))



forest <- ggplot(data=forestdat, aes(x=label, y=PR, ymin =lowlim, ymax = uplim)) +
  geom_pointrange(size = 1) + 
  geom_hline(yintercept=1, lty=2) +  # add a dotted line at x=1 after flip
  coord_flip() +  # flip coordinates (puts labels on y axis)
  ylab("PR (95% CI)") +
  scale_x_discrete(labels = rowlab) + #this didn't work
  scale_y_continuous(trans='log10') #this didn't work either

forest
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure it isn't working -- the log scale just doesn't change very much in that narrow range.

You no longer need `coord_flip` for most geoms, since ggplot 3.3.0 in 2020:

```
ggplot(data=forestdat, aes(x=PR, y=label, xmin =lowlim, xmax = uplim)) +
  geom_pointrange(size = 1) + 
  geom_vline(xintercept=1, lty=2) +  # add a dotted line at x=1 after flip
  ylab("PR (95% CI)") +
  scale_y_discrete(labels = rowlab) + 
  scale_x_continuous(trans='log10')
```

You might expand the range a bit to see it clearer:

```
+ scale_x_continuous(trans=scales::log10_trans(),
                     limits = c(0.8,1.4),
                     breaks = seq(0.4,1.4, 0.1))
```

[image]